# Language Code Stripping Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I feel like I'm pretty close to the solution here, but I can't quite seem to figure it out. My goal is to take the set of strings one at a time, `[ 'en', 'en-us', 'en_us', 'zh-hans-TW' ]` and produce `[ 'en', 'en', 'en', 'zh-hans' ]`. I've tried a few different things, but don't have quite the right solution.

This is the closest I've come, I believe, matching all but 'en'.

`/([a-zA-Z-_]+)[-_].+/`
(One or more of aA-zZ chars or -_ followed by - or _ and additional chars)

I tried negative lookahead (which I'm not real good at), and came up with this which over matches and captures the whole string

`/([a-zA-Z-_]+)(?![-_].+)/`
(One or more aA-zZ chars or -_ not followed by - or _ with additional characters)

Could someone point out the right solution here?

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: Javascript in this case.

Comment: I am afraid this regex flavor won't let you use a clean and lean 1-pattern regex solution since you need to match part of the string in some strings, and not to match in others. You could easily do this in .NET, but not with JavaScript.

Comment: While my issue is in Javascript, I would be interested to see the solution in another language as well. Could you link an example of what you're talking about in .NET?

Comment: Here is an example in .NET that will match and hold the required strings in ${my_result}: `^(?:(?<my_result>en)(?:[_-][a-z]*?)?|(?<my_result>(?!.*?en)[^\r\n]*?))$`. Just these strings must be tested separately, no multiline/singleline modes should be used.

Comment: If this is not a multiline string, why do you include `\r\n`? Also, your results seem to only be handling the 'en' strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72247/discussion-between-stribizhev-and-shortstuffsushi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of matching the portions of the strings you wish to keep, you could remove the ends of the strings you do not want to keep:

```
/[-_][a-z]+$/i
```

Here is an implementation in Javascript:

```
var array1 = [ 'en', 'en-us', 'en_us', 'zh-hans-TW' ];

var array2 = array1.map(function(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-_][a-z]+$/i, "");
});

console.log(array2);
```

This outputs:

```
[ 'en', 'en', 'en', 'zh-hans' ]
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea. I'm not going to accept this just yet, as I'm curious to see a solution solving with regex, but I hadn't thought of this.

Comment: Just realized I never followed up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to be more general. For instance, `de-DE-u-co-phonebk` is also a valid language code (the stuff starting with `-u...` represents Unicode options for collation order etc.). I'm assuming you want to strip off everything starting from the country code, which by the standard is supposed to be uppercase. If you want to do this with a regexp, then

```
function strip_country_code(lang) { return lang.replace(/[-_][A-Z][A-Z].*$/, ''); }
```

Of course, this will fail on `en-us`, which is invalid; it should be `en-US`. You have to decide if and how to handle invalid language codes such as this.

That's just one reason that you would be better off using available libraries to process language codes if possible. Take a look at the [JS internationalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-8), which has several ways to parse locale codes and find the "best" one. However, browser support is limited. So you might want to look for something off the shelf. But I can't put my finger on anything at the moment.

The JED library uses [the following regexp](https://github.com/jed/locale/blob/master/lib/index.js#l28) to extract segments:

```
str.match(/[a-z]+/gi)
```

but then assumes that the second segment if present is always the country, so this logic would fail on `zh-hans-TW`.

You should also consider who is going to be consuming the result of your string manipulation. Are you saying that there is some library, or API, that can *only* handle the part of the locale string preceding the country code? You should ensure that that is in fact the case. For instance, I believe that moment.js also will handle different locale strings properly.

Comment: I'm not particularly looking for alternatives to the problem I posed. I don't want to use an alternative library, or anything like that, and I'm not pulling the data from the browser -- the codes are provided from elsewhere. The last piece, splitting by word is potentially an interesting idea, though.